Knowing all the cucumber tags related to a set of test cases before running them in Java
I am working on a test project in Java using Cucumber and JUnit5. I am running both API and UI test cases for a web application. For the API test cases we are using XSRF tokens as an extra layer of security (besides the usual bearer token). Today I am getting this token in the BeforeAll hook, because it can be used for all test cases in the execution, but I would like to generate this token only when there is at least one API test in the list of tests, it doesn't make sense to generate it if I'm running only UI test cases.
The problem is this: how can I find out if there is at least one API test case in my test case list (that I am going to select using other tags) before the execution even begins?
The versions of the dependencies in my POM file:
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit-platform.version>1.11.2</junit-platform.version>
    <maven-surefire-junit-platform.version>3.5.1</maven-surefire-junit-platform.version>
    <selenium.version>4.25.0</selenium.version>
    <rest-assured.version>5.5.0</rest-assured.version>
    <log4j.version>2.24.1</log4j.version>
    <json.version>20240303</json.version>
    <cucumber.version>7.20.1</cucumber.version>
    <serenity.version>4.2.3</serenity.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.13.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.5.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.4.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>3.5.1</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
    <serenity-maven-plugin.version>4.2.3</serenity-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>


I suggest you to go other way and generate token when it requested first time, then store it for future use.
